# routerLinkActive for anchor

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a `navbar` with popup. I want to be able to activate the `anchor` of dropdown  as well.

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li class="nav-item">
      **<a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link>Parent</a> **
        <div class="dropdown-menu>
             <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/"  
                    routerLinkActive="nav-element-active">Overview</a>
             <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/Overview2"
                    routerLinkActive="nav-element-active">Overview2</a>
        </div>
    </li>...
</ul>
```

the `<a>` should be activated as well on dropdown navigation. Is it possible using `routerLinkactive`?

Answer (score 0):

On your component.ts file add
import { RouterLinkActive } from '@angular/router';

and add it on the directives array. It will work for you.

*The solution i gave as per angular 2.0 rc-5 version*